# How to connect to istio ip address

Tags: azure-aks, istio, istio-gateway

Team we have aks cluster in azure, we also have istio ingress load balancer ip address, but we are trying to ping that command but it is throwing request timed out.. We tries with telnet commands and also normal ping ip address command. This is for testing. Can anyone help how we can connect to istio ip address ?

Comment: Assuming you have just installed Istio and created a gateway and VS (otherwise see https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/), ping won't work as uses ICMP protocol. You need to test with curl for example, or telnet to the port 80 or 443 by default (are the ports exposed).

Comment: we tried with all the commands like curl telnet and ping but it is not working is it like any firewall issue is there or nsg log issue is there? Just we need to check what is the reason behind this? yes the ports are exposed. any idea on this

Comment: istio is installed already and external ip address we can check with kubectl command. IP is exposed but unable to connect to it

Comment: what is the output of doing a curl -v to the exposed IP?

Comment: timed out curl 28: failed to connect error